# position of adverb

Tags: adverbs

I watched the movie Dr. Dolittle. A character dragonfly which was burnt by a dragon's sniff in a cave said this:

> I will meet whosoever survives outside.

To me it is fine because it is:

```
Subject+ verb+ object+ adverb
```

But someone has said to me:
Isn't the position of adverb a little weird in this? Doesn't this give meaning that the character is saying:

> I will meet the one who survives outside.

But I think this sentence means:

```
I will meet the person outside who survives here inside the cave.
```

Who is right, him or me?

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. It can be interpreted either way (although I would favour your interpretation).

Comment: Your friend is wrong. The context clearly indicates that the dragonfly is talking about surviving the dragon.

Answer (score -1):

This sentence is ambiguous. I don't know the situation what you think about, but the meaning of this sentence is different in situation.

Comment: Lee, you need to redraft your second sentence to make the meaning clear.  The phrase **is different in situation** is neither clear nor idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is like:

I will meet him outside.

whosoever = him

It is like:

I will gift whosoever secures 90% a bicycle.